# vlan limit in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: vlan

I'm using the same netplan file in 20 as I was using in 18. It sets up 42 vlan bridges. This works fine in 18. However, in 20, I seem to only get 22 of them assigned randomly. Is there some vlan limit that has been introduced in ubuntu 20?

Comment: Is there another place to ask these kind of questions? I've asked quite a few lately, and don't really get answers.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1881244

Comment: Seems that disabling ipv6 lets this work.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling ipv6 lets this work correctly.